# Destructor must do the reverse of what constructors do for static members?

Tags: c++, destructor, static-members

```
class A
{
    int id;
    static int count;
public:
    A()
    {
        count++;
        id = count;
        cout << "constructor called " << id << endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        //count -=2; /*Keypoint is here. */
                   /*Uncomment it later. But result doesn't change*/
        cout << "destructor called " << id << endl;
    }
};

int A::count = 0;

int main()
{
    A a[2];
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
constructor called 1
constructor called 2
destructor called 2
destructor called 1
```

The question is:
  even if you uncomment the `//count -=2;`
  the result is still the same.

Does that mean that if the constructor increments the static member by 1,then the destructor must decrement it exactly by 1 also, and you can't change the behaviour of it?

Comment: Erm, the destructor prints `id`, not `count`. How do you know `count`  gets decremented?

Comment: Oh,I'm so careless,so silly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing accesses `count` after the first destructor is invoked. The destructor does exactly what you code it to do, either modifying `count` or not. But you won't see the effect unless you access `count` in some way.